# É seguro guardar o paymentID do paypal na base de dados?

Tags: api

Ola, gostaria de vos perguntar se é uma boa pratica guardar o paymentID do paypal após o processo de compra?

Eu gostaria de utilizar esse ID para fazer verificações internas mas estou realmente indeciso porque penso que isto se torne numa vulnerabilidade.

Agradecia uma opinião vossa!

Cumprimentos !